# Xlib: Move Window Outside of Desktop Bounds

Tags: c++, xlib

Is it possible to move an X11 window outside of the desktop using xlib?
For example I want to position a window at -300, -300 and do so using the XMoveWindow function.

```
XMoveWindow( dpy, win, -300, -300 );
```

So the desired result would be something like this:

```
+--------+
|   win  |
|     +--|-------------+
|     |  |             |
+--------+             |
      |     Desktop    |
      |                |
      |                |
      +----------------+
```

Except the window is moved to 0, 0 instead:

```
+--------+-------+
|        |       |
|   win  |       |
|        |       |
+--------+       |
|     Desktop    |
+----------------+
```

I can manually drag the window out of the screen beyond 0, 0 which makes me think it should be possible to do this with Xlib?

Comment: The window manager might be overriding your applications MoveWindow request.

Comment: Yup, you're correct. Just tested some more things. and setting the override redirect attribute allows me to move the window outside of the desktop.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I'm facing the same issue but not quite sure how to get it working in code.

Comment: Yeah in order to let the window manager move the window out of desktop bounds you need to use the override redirect attribute on the window. But this comes with a new set of problems since the window manager will no longer do any work for you.